# Visual Studio 2015 - Network debug tool shows 'Not applicable' - Why?

Tags: networking, visual-studio-2015

I am debugging some network issues in a desktop application that makes requests to a service using RestSharp.  The actual problem is failing authentication to the service in some limited scenarios, although that is really not relevant to my question.

I have been using Fiddler4 but that has not helped.  I wondered if the network tool in Visual Studio 2015 might give some other light on the problem.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/05/04/introducing-visual-studios-network-tool/

However, when I start the performance profiler the Network tool is grayed out and in the list of 'Not Applicable Tools' (incidentally my menu structure is somewhat different to the screen shot shown in the link above.)I wondered if my Professional Edition does not have the tool enabled, but research on the Microsoft site does not seem to give any information about that.  The word 'network' does not appear on this page

https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to access the network diagnostic tool to monitor my application ?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, the tool only works with the WinRT client. Is that what you are using?

Referring to the comment at [the link you provided](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/05/04/introducing-visual-studios-network-tool/):

> Operations made using the old .NET HttpClient API aren’t captured.

Comment: Thanks !!  I was not using the WinRT client.  I eventually found the answer to my problem by other means.

Comment: This is the correct answer and should be marked as such.